# How to extend and use MongoCursor class

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to extend the MongoCursor class to do some extra stuff while querying/sorting/etc stuff from my Mongo database.

The PHP documentation clearly states that I can and should use the `doQuery()` method for this, as all querying stuff internaly calls this method. There even is a sample for an overriden Cursor class. So, no problem so far...

But now, how can I convice my MongoCollection class to return this new MyCursor class instead of the normal MongoCursor?

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.doquery.php

Sample MyCursor:

```
class MyCursor extends MongoCursor {
    protected function doQuery() {
        // Do some custom and very special stuff here!
        MongoCursor::doQuery();
    }
}
```

---

**Some clarifications**

I can create my own MongoCollection class (I created a Decorator, but simply Extension would work same).

I can also create my own MongoCursor class with my own code as shown above.

The problem is not how to create my own MongoCursor class but how I can make a collection return this custom Cursor class from a call to the find method. Afaik, the find method currently returns a hard coded MongoCursor class and can not be changed to return something else. The call to the cursors constructor is inside that find method and not accessible.

I would leave it at that and just go home grab a beer and use some other database, but the sample on extending MongoCursor from the PHP documentation suggests that there IS a way to use a custom cursor.

Answer (score -1):

You need to extend the class `MongoCollection` (and hence `MongoClient`) as well.

Another solution would be to encapsulate the original `MongoCursor` into `MyCursor`, instance-wise, as in the following example:

```
class MyCursor extends MongoCursor {

        private $baseCursor;

        protected function doQuery() {
                // Do some custom and very special stuff here!
#               MongoCursor::doQuery();
        }

        public function __construct($baseCursor=null) {
                if (!is_null($baseCursor)) {
                        $this->baseCursor = $baseCursor;
                } else {
                        $this->baseCursor = new MongoCursor($this);
                }
        }

        public function __call($name, $arguments) {
                if (in_array($name, get_class_methods('MongoCursor'))) {
                        return $this->baseCursor->$name($arguments);
                } else {
                        return $this->$name($arguments);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I did, but I can't just override the find method for example as I dont know what it does. And since `parent::find` would alread return a MongoCursor, there is no option for me to change that later.

Comment: This part is clear, however, the constructor is never called by modifyable PHP code but somewhere within the MongoCollection:find method. So, I simply do not know how to invoke construction of the cursor myself.

Comment: And even if I use this Decorater approach where I encapsulate the original cursor into my own, the encapsulated cursor will of course never call the doQuery method within the Decorator but only it's own. So, saldy not an option.

Comment: But now you can override `find()` and let it encapsulate a `MongoCursor` returned by `parent::find()` into a `MyCursor`, before returning the latter to the caller.

Comment: No, I cant. If I encapslate the returned `MongoCursor` into `MyCursor` via a Decorator as shown in your sample, it will still call it's own doQuery method inside `MongoCursor` and not in `MyCursor`. (Clarification: doQuery is called from the Cursor itself during it's query Phase and not from anyone else outside)